# Php mail() with xampp and hMailServer

Tags: php, windows, email, xampp

I have windows 2012 server. I have installed email server (hMailServer) which is configured and send / receive emails correctly.

But when I want send mail from php, (I have to use mail() function), nothing happen.

In php.ini i set up:

```
[mail function]
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like     Mercury
SMTP = 127.0.0.1
 smtp_port = 25
```

any idea where can be problem? Thank you

edit:
I tried

```
auth_username = smtp-username
auth_password = smtp-password
sendmail_from = you@yourserver.com
```

with different smtp servers and always receive this error:

```
Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 530 SMTP authentication is required.
```

Answer (score 1):

hMailServer configurated use localhost? Maybe you need use SMTP authentification?

try use remote credentials like this

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = mail.yourserver.com
smtp_port = 25
auth_username = smtp-username
auth_password = smtp-password
sendmail_from = you@yourserver.com
```

Comment: I did what u said, but get error - Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 530 SMTP authentication is required. I tried more my smtp mails, but always same error.